# CSV to H2 - character encoding missmatch

Tags: java, linux, windows, csv, h2

In my app, I:

- let Hibernate create H2 DB
- populate DB through JDBC SQL statement with CSV import (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM CSVREAD(file.csv)`). File is in UTF-8 encoding.

On Linux special characters in the DB are correct.

On Windows (default encoding cp1250) special characters are incorrect.

When I try different CSV file encoding (cp1250, iso-8859-2), it works on Windows, but not on Linux.

Is there any way to tell H2 it needs to respect UTF-8 encoding on Windows?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? By default, Java projects in Eclipse in Windows use a different encoding. Changing it to UTF8 in the project preferences may solve your problem.

Comment: How did you use `CSVREAD` exactly? Did you use `CSVREAD('file.csv', null, 'charset=UTF-8')` [as documented](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#csv_options)?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, it worked. I searched only in functions help page, not grammar.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 needs to be set in the [options parameter of the `CSVREAD` function](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#csv_options), as follows:

```
CSVREAD('file.csv', null, 'charset=UTF-8')
```